# WP7 MediaElement download problems

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, mediaelement

I'm running into problems on the WP7 with MediaElement downloading a 128kbps mp3 stream from a web service for a music player app that i'm working on. The file downloads correctly when the wp7 is on a wifi connection, but downloading sometimes stops when off of wifi. The problem is that i'm not getting any errors or exceptions when the downloading fails and the MediaElement state is "playing". MediaElement runs right past the downloaded portion of the stream and acts like it is playing, but there is nothing to play since the download stopped. I can somewhat replicate this issue based upon my location and using the 3g instead of wifi, so i believe it is due to a low connection. I don't believe any code needs to be shown in this instance, but i try to post something. I want to know if I have any control over this? Are there any other events I could use to detect when the download has failed? Is there another way I could download a mp3 stream that is more reliable and play it? Is there another player/component I should try?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could always use `MediaStreamSource` to try to handle the download and implement streaming, to some extent. It is a more "painful" way of doing this since you will have to work with an extra media layer, but it pays off by improving playback stability.

Here is a starter [example by Tim Heuer](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2010/08/16/download-and-store-media-for-playback-in-windows-phone-7-using-mediastreamsource.aspx). Take a look specifically at how he takes advantage of a custom implementation of `MediaStreamSource`. [Here](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ManagedMediaHelpers) is a more complex sample.

If streaming is not a requirement, you could download the file (and store it in the Isolated Storage) and then play from there.

Comment: Thanks, Dennis! Very nice link! I've thought of this method but i was a little afraid that I would lose the ability to playback the stream as it downloads which is extremely important to me. Do you know if I will have any problems with playback in the MediaElement while stream is downloading?

Comment: You shouldn't if you build a content verification mechanism. All you have to do is make sure that the stream is constantly renewed and if there is a hiccup, re-download.